# How to stop foreman in heroku?

Tags: heroku, foreman

```
foreman start
```

runs an app that i can visit on localhost

How do I stop this and get back to the prompt and continue playing around with heroku?

I am on a Windows Machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-C worked for me, but that terminates the process. (I'm on Ubuntu though, but I think the command's the same)

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu and it works, but it breaks my console... I can no longer type in it. I have to close it up and start a new one. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually I can type commands but I can't see my characters typed in. Writing the "reset" command fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I also found Ctrl+C to work but only upon a page reload.

If I just hit Ctrl+C without any page requests, they seem to have queued up.  If I hit it multiple times, I receive multiple "Sinatra has finished his set" messages when I finally do refresh the page.